# Setting cache size doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, caching, webview

I have an app that has a webview that loads a HTML file with lots of javascript for use with Google maps. I want to use LOTS of cache of the webview (for the maps) as much as possible specially offline (except in ONE case, see below), so I added this in the Activity that holds the webview:

```
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewmap);
    ws = myWebView.getSettings();
    ws.setUserAgentString(ws.getUserAgentString() + " AveWebview");
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    ws.setAppCacheMaxSize( 500 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 500MB // DEPRECATED IN API 18

    ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    ws.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    ws.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    ws.setDomStorageEnabled(true);     
    ws.setCacheMode((online) ? WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK : WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
```

It works, I see maps offline, but the cache stays below 40MB instead of 500MB, deleting stuff. I know that the cache condition is deprecated in API 18, but I am below API 18.... What am I doing wrong and how can I raise the cache size?

I bet this is a duplicate... but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

Thanks!

L.

Answer (score 0):

Browser cache stuff is stored under /data partition. So maybe you need to make sure there's 500M empty spaces under /data.  I remember there is no specific limitation regarding maximum app cache size.

Comment: As you read in the code I posted, I set 500m for the cache, but the app never uses more than 40. No idea why.... Anyway, I store the cache in the external sd (code not above). Thanks.